# Можно ли выразиться так? 1. Птицы гомонят наперебой. 2. Птичьи стаи гомонят наперебой

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли выразиться так?

1. Птицы гомонят наперебой.
2. Птичьи стаи гомонят наперебой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, можно. Почему бы и нет?

Answer (score 2):

Я воспринимаю такое выражение как *стилистическую неудачу*: "**наперебой**" означает, что люди или (здесь) особи **перебивают** друг дружку, пытаясь что-то сообщить, заявить о чём-то (напр. о праве на добычу, место под солнцем и т. п.). Однако употреблением слова "гомон" пишущий уже дал оценку такому "сообщению" со стороны как "невразумительный шум" (гомон). Соответственно, издавая **шум**, будь он коллективным или индивидуальным, нельзя (с позиции того же автора) этим "**перебить**" кого-либо, в результате эти два слова не сочетаются, выглядят *непоследовательно* и даже тавтологично. Такой проблемы нет там, где говорится напр. о "свисте" или "крике" (язык у птиц такой - они на нём общаются, а не просто шумят без толку), но не о "гомоне".

Со "стаей" - ещё хуже: выходит, что одна стая пытается *перебить* другую шумом, - не дождавшись своей *очереди зашуметь*.

Comment: Интересная точка зрения!

Comment: Шумят, перебивая друг друга, почему нет?

Comment: Шумят, перебивая друг друга = перебивают друг друга (напр. пытаясь что-то заявить на птичьем языке), и в результате получается _общий шум_, такое выражение имеет свою логику. Здесь две глагольных формы, которые по смыслу можно соотнести как _причину_ (деепричастие) и _следствие_ (глагол). Попытка же увидеть в деепричастии _образ действия_ вместо его причины приводит к странному смыслу: выходит, что зачем-то "перебивают друг друга шумом". Именно это выходит и в выражении с _наречием_ ("наперебой"), которое может обозначить _только образ действия_.

Answer (score 1):

[ГОМОНИ́ТЬ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/102966/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C), -ня́т; нсв. Разг. Громко разговаривать; шуметь (**о многих**). *Толпа глухо гомонила. Дети громко гомонят, смеются.* / **О птицах, насекомых, животных.** *Гомонят галки перед дождём. Громко гомонят шмели. Разноголосо гомонят лягушки.*

*«Пи-лить, пи-лить!» — разрывают солнечную тишину верткие синицы. И воробьи неподалеку гомонят наперебой* (А. Стрижев. Времена года).
*На той стороне Дона в лесу наперебой высвистывали соловьи* (М. Шолохов. Тихий Дон).
*«Кря-кря! — успокаивающе крякали утки наперебой* (И. Полуянов. Горох на тысячу дорог).
*Давно ли гомонили хоры прилетных птиц, подымалась трава, одевались кусты* (С. Багров. Сорочье поле).

Comment: Римма, простите, что затрагиваю такой мелкий вопрос, но мне кажется, что вы не знаете, что двойной пробел нужен, только если следующий абзац начинается со следующей строчки, а если строчка пустая, они не нужны. Я понимаю, конечно, что на вид ничего не меняется и можно это не трогать. По крайней мере, надеюсь, вы не будете на меня удивлённо смотреть за то, что я их часто убираю, — у меня это на автомате получается. Короче, делайте, как удобно, сказал просто на тот случай, если не знали.

Comment: А я никак не могла понять-увидеть в ответах — чегой-то Вы все время по одному знаку изничтожаете? Приму к сведению. Но ведь на конфигурацию ответа и восприятие такие "дополнительные" пробелы не влияют. Зачем же тогда из-за такой (никому не видной) мелочи делать правку? _Используйте редактирование для исправления ошибок, улучшения форматирования и разъяснения смысла сообщения_ — так написано в "справке".

Comment: Ну вот я и боялся, что Вы будете недовольны. Я сказал, что на автомате так само получается.))